# How to use Angular to create a white label

Tags: angular, white-labelling

I googled some article about creating a white label website which is able to have different css styles based on the domain name, but I have not found any way to work it out using the separated frontend/backend tech stack.

My project consists of an angular 5 frontend and a Java backend which serves only JSON result. So I think getting CSS file from backend server is not applicable (I don't know if it's correct).

My question is: how do I create a white label which can change css style according to the subdomain address using only Angular(5 or latest version if necessary)?
Is this the best practice to do it this way? If not, what should I do without modifying my architecture (separated frontend/backend)?

Comment: Yes, it's completely possible and can work with Angular. What have you tried?